# Finite posets built by coning initial segments in an auxiliary ordering

Tags: co.combinatorics, ct.category-theory, posets

Let $P$ be a finite poset, and let $p \in P$ be a maximal element. Then $P = (P \setminus p) \cup_{P_{<p}} P_{\leq p}$. Conversely, if $Q$ is a poset and $S \subseteq Q$ is downward-closed, then $P = Q \cup_S S^{\triangleright}$ is a poset with one more element.

Applying this iteratively, every finite poset $P$ admits an ordering $P = \{p_1,\dots, p_n\}$ such that for every $1 \leq i \leq n$, the set $\{p_1, \dots, p_i\}$ is downward-closed in $P$. In this case, $\{p_1,\dots,p_{i+1}\} = \{p_1,\dots, p_i\} \cup_{S_i} S_i^\triangleright$ for a unique downward-closed $S_i \subseteq \{p_1,\dots,p_i\}$.

**Question:** For which posets $P$ does there exist such an ordering where each $S_i$ is of the form $S_i = \{p_1,\dots, p_{j(i)}\}$ -- i.e. $S_i$ is downward closed not only in $P$ but also with respect to the linear ordering we've chosen?

Comment: Can you explain some of the notation? What does the subscript on the union mean? What does the triangle in the exponent mean?

Comment: @SamHopkins The subscript on the union is there because I’m thinking of it as a pushout and I’m indicating what I’m pushing out over. Given $S$, $S^\triangleright$ is meant to denote $S$ with a new top element adjoined.

Comment: So we must have $S_i = \{p \in \{p_1,\ldots,p_i\}\colon p < p_{i+1}\}$, right? And then the answer to your question is: only for totally ordered $P$ (a.k.a. chains)?

Comment: I think we get more than chains. For example, $2\leftarrow 1 \to 3$ works with $S_1 = S_2 = \{ 1\}$, the freedom is to choose $j(i)$

Comment: Ah, I see. So unit interval orders a.k.a. semiorders (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiorder) should satisfy this property. But you definitely get more because a chain plus an incomparable element is okay too.

Comment: Interesting! I think the posets I’m talking about are closed under induced subposets, so there should be a forbidden subposet characterization as for semiorder s. And I think that $ x \to y  ~ z \to w $ is not one of my posets but 1\to 2 \to 3 ~ 4$ is. So maybe slightly more general than semiorders — maybe semiorder union discrete

Comment: You might also want to look at just interval orders (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_order) though I don’t quite see why these are achievable.